# Error while running DFA in R at the predict function

Tags: r

I'm attempting to run a cv DFA on a set of species X site data (species are columns, sites are rows) with a grouping row named "ZONE".

I'm using a stock script I've successfully used before, but now I'm getting a new error from the predict function that I can't make heads or tails of.

My code is simply:

```
data2.lda<-lda(ZONE~SP1+SP2+SP3+SP4+SP5+SP6+SP7+SP8+SP9+SP10+SP11+SP12+SP13+SP14+SP15
,data=data2.x, Cna.action="na.omit",CV=TRUE)

list(data2.lda)

data2.lda.p<-predict(data2.lda,newdata=data2.lda.x(,c[2:17]))$class
data2.lda.p
```

the error I receive is:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
>    no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list"

My data are in the same form as previous uses of this code.
Where did I go wrong? 
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE: I've figured out that the issue involves the cross validation portion of the code. Are there additional rules for cross validating an LDA that I'm missing when it comes to coding in R?**

Comment: I think you meant to use `data2.x` rather than `data2.lda.x` in `predict`

Comment: Making that change didn't make a difference unfortunately but thank you for your comment. However, when I abandon the cross validation (remove CV=TRUE) the code works perfectly. I know this is the proper command, are there additional rules for using leave one out cross validation that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per PCantalupo's answer, I managed to arrive at my goal. The cross validation procedure needs to be applied during the predict model, not the original model. The functional code is:

```
data2.lda<-lda(ZONE~SP1+SP2+SP3+SP4+SP5+SP6+SP7+SP8+SP9+SP10+SP11+SP12+SP13+SP14+SP15
,data=data2.x, Cna.action="na.omit")

list(data2.lda)

data2.lda.p<-predict(data2.lda,CV=TRUE,newdata=data1[c(2:17)])$class
data2.lda.p
tab<-table(data2.lda.p,data2[,1])
tab
summary(table(data2.lda.p,data2[,1]))
diag(prop.table(tab,1))
sum(diag(prop.table(tab)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `predict` requires a model object for its first argument. When you run `lda` with the `CV=T` option, it returns a list object not a model object. The `lda` documentation says

> If CV = TRUE the return value is a list with components class, the MAP
>   classification (a factor), and posterior, posterior probabilities for
>   the classes.
>
> Otherwise it is an object of class "lda" containing the
>   following components:

Comment: Thank you for your response, that helps me understand what the problem is. However, if that's the case then how are you supposed to implement the CV option? A DFA has little value without a leave one out cross validation. 

New question: what is the proper way to code the CV=TRUE option for a model I wish to predict?

Comment: You create your model without the CV=TRUE option and use `predict` on this model. The CV=TRUE option is there for you to check how accurate your model is. Then it is up to you to decide if you want to abandon this model and generate a new one.